# remove writetimeout for individual api gin

Tags: go, timeout, server-sent-events, go-gin

```
a.httpServer = &http.Server{
Handler: c.Handler(a.router.Router),
WriteTimeout:      cfg.HTTP.WriteTimeout,
ReadTimeout:       cfg.HTTP.ReadTimeout,
IdleTimeout:       cfg.HTTP.IdleTimeout,
ReadHeaderTimeout: cfg.HTTP.ReadHeaderTimeout,
}
```

I initialize a write timeout to the server, can I somehow delete this timeout for the api where I use sse?

```
v2.GET("/stream", HeadersMiddleware(), r.serveHTTP(), func(c \*gin.Context) {
    v, ok := c.Get("clientChan")
    if !ok {
        return
}
    clientChan, ok := v.(ClientChan)
    fmt.Println(v)
    if !ok {
    return
}
    c.Stream(func(w io.Writer) bool {
    person := Person{Name: "John", Age: 30}
    jsonBytes,  := json.Marshal(person)
    if msg, ok := \<-clientChan; ok {
    c.SSEvent("message", jsonBytes)
    log.Printf(msg)
    return true
}

            
    log.Printf("false")
    return true
            })
        })
```

I haven't found anything on the internet that could work correctly.

Comment: Use [ResponseController](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseController).

Comment: You can use `rc := http.NewResponseController(ctx.Writer)` and reset deadline with `rc.SetWriteDeadline(time.Time{})`.